# How to verify the downloaded files by .torrent?

Tags: checksum

Many Ubuntu versions like 18.04.1, 18.04.2, 16.04.3, kubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, couldn't find it's checksum of .iso file from websites, but the .iso can be downloaded from a torrent file providers like https://linuxtracker.org, does the torrent file provide the checksums for the .iso?

Answer (score 3):

The torrent mechanism itself has builtin checksumming of each piece of the torrent contents (each piece is identified by a hash, so to know you got the correct piece, its hash has to be checked). So any decent torrent client should be doing that anyway.

However, for manual verification, the official Ubuntu ISO archives (https://releases.ubuntu.com/ and https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/) have signed checksums of the ISO files. You can also find torrent files there. For example, for 18.04.6:

- The main directory: https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.6/
- The `SHA256SUMS` file: https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.6/SHA256SUMS
- The signature for the `SHA256SUMS` file: https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.6/SHA256SUMS.gpg
- The torrent file: https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.6/ubuntu-18.04.6-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Obsolete releases like 18.04.1 can be found in https://old-releases.ubuntu.com, for example, with https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/:

- https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/SHA256SUMS
- https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/SHA256SUMS.gpg
- https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/ubuntu-18.04-live-server-amd64.iso.torrent

Other flavours can be found in https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/, e.g., with Kubuntu:

- https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/
- https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/kubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
- https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/SHA256SUMS
- https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/SHA256SUMS.gpg

Comment: https://old-releases.ubuntu.com has all about ubuntu, but unlucky for other flavours.
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/ has nothing about 20.04.2 or 18.04.2, https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/, https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/, https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/ also has removed the old checksums.

Comment: https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/kubuntu/releases/ has no my version.

Comment: @user536180 ah well, in that case the best option is probably to try the Internet Archive.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20190403134135/cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases but the link named 18.04.1 inaccessible.

Comment: stuffs in https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/20.04.3/release/ all is 20.04.4

Comment: @user536180 For the Xubuntu one https://web.archive.org/web/20200130171901/http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/18.04.1/release/ for the Ubuntu mate one, I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: That day is nice can show any thing I want!